# Is Apache Kafka polling more "efficient" than gRPC streams or HTTP polling?

Tags: git, apache-kafka, rabbitmq, grpc

I'm designing a distributed system that has a single source of the changes (eg. text file) on the server and diff consumers. We need to deliver the changes granularly to the client (ideally as fast as we can with for at small traffic/maintenance cost).

I'm considering few options:

- HTTP + REST client requests (polling)
- Apache Kafka
- gRPC streams
- queues-based solutions (eg. RabbitMQ)
- trivial git clone

What's the cost of Apache Kafka polling (traffic size)? How can i roughly measure the amount of traffic from N clients (can be a billion consumers potentially at the same time) with M milliseconds polling interval? Is it more efficient than gRPC stream (the way you understand "efficient")?

Any better solution alternatives?

Comment: Kafka polling will be over TCP with binary serialization. That would be faster than GRPC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traffic overhead of all your polling solutions will probably be similar if you use the same polling interval.

For gRPC streams and maybe some JMS protocols there will be very low traffic if there is no data to be sent, but there will always be heartbeat packets.

But you should check the limitations of the number of clients. If you talk about millions of consumers, you don't want them to have an open TCP/IP socket all of the time, because that will kill your OS.

If you would run it using kafka, on top of the open TCP/IP sockets, you will also keep each consumer's offset on the server. If you would have 1000 updates for the text file, you will have only 1000 messages in the actual kafka topic, but the `__consumer_offsets` internal topics will have millions of entries, one for each consumer.

For really large scales (like IoT), they recommend combining it with MQTT: https://www.confluent.io/blog/iot-streaming-use-cases-with-kafka-mqtt-confluent-and-waterstream/. In that blog, they mention that Kafka was not built for tens of thousands connections.

Using GIT seems to be better suited to me, although I'm not sure how well it can cache things in-memory server-side.

Using a custom HTTP polling client seems to be the simplest solution, and there are probably olutions using the Etag header or something similar. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag

Comment: Kafka consumer offsets aren't stored by the polling client, but if they were, it's a basic Hashmap, so not huge memory overhead

Comment: Thanks for the advice. In my particular case i'd save the offset on the client side and seek to the offset (already having working poc) every time the client is started. However i haven't double checked the offset is not saved on Kafka side too

Comment: @GreyFairer are you saying that Kafka can't handle a billion clients too (or it's just not out-of-box solution)?

Comment: For really large scales (like IoT), they recommend combining it with MQTT: https://www.confluent.io/blog/iot-streaming-use-cases-with-kafka-mqtt-confluent-and-waterstream/. In that blog, they mention that Kafka was not built for tens of thousands connections.

Comment: Consumer offsets are stored in a separate internal topic on the server:  __consumer_offsets. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think polling will be an efficient solution here. Sounds like you want to look at Zookeeper or Consul KV Store which allow you to broadcast changes to watchers and create locks on said entities as they're changing

If you do want to use Git, or these options take a look at Central Dogma - https://line.github.io/centraldogma/